# OpenGL lines with transparency causing white to appear

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine

This might be a weird question and a long one so bear with me, thanks.

So a short intro for this one. I am trying to represent a camera's vision by using raycasts so that it can "see" objects. The collision is working fine. Now I am trying to visualize the "vision" the camera has by using lines. At first I started used the built in debug.drawLine/Ray but there is no flexibility with the lines/rays drawn with that. Then I moved on to openGL and drawing the lines. I have gotten the functionality I wanted but in doing so I have run into a problem that I cannot fix.

[image]

Above you can see that the lines I am drawing have transparency and they are supposed to. My thinking is that since the lines are transparent and all coming from a singluar point, the transparency is "stacking" and causing them to go white which is something that I do not want.

I tried using a Material for the line material but I cannot get the lines to be transparent with that. So I decided to find a unity topic that gives you a built in shader through script which is below.

```c#
void createLineMaterial()
{
    if(!lineMaterial)
    {
        Shader shader = Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored");
        lineMaterial = new Material(shader);
        lineMaterial.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        //Turn on Alpha blending
        lineMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
        lineMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.DstAlpha);
        //Turn backface culling off
        lineMaterial.SetInt("_Cull", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode.Off);
        //Turn off depth writes
        lineMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
    }
}
```

To clarify further I have included another picture below.
[image]

I try to get the width vision and then do height sweeps to get a 3D representation of the environment.

The real question is about the shader. How can I use transparency without it stacking? I am new to shaders and really don't know much about them.

Thanks for reading and have a great day!

Comment: I....can't think of a way to fix this. I was going to say a custom shader that handles transparency differently, but then it occurred to me that that won't work.  Hmm...actually, if you used a *stencil mask* that could work. Then that shader would only draw where it hasn't drawn before, limiting the stacking to 1.

Comment: @Draco18s So I would like each plane to be drawn, the end goal is to make a solid looking transparent object that shows collisions within it. This just really has me stumped.

Comment: Right. I know what you're trying to do. The *only* way I can think of achieving this is through a custom shader using a [stencil mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html).

Comment: @Draco18s thanks, I will look into stencil masks and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Shader code isn't *that* difficult, but it takes some getting used to. I don't enjoy it enough to try and write it for you. But if you run into problems I can answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Z-Test might be helpful.

```
lineMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
lineMaterial.SetInt("_ZTest", (int) UnityEngine.Rendering.CompareFunction.Less );
```

Comment: So it solves the white showing up problem which I do thank you for! Now the problem is with doing a Z-Test the multiple lines below the first set of rays barely shows up, like the transparency is being taken away from the top layer. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sorting of draw calls might help, but you have to sort all the lines drawing with that material. I.e. if you have multiple components and each is used to draw its own set of lines, then now you need to create one shared list of lines and sort it before drawing.

Comment: float DistanceToLine( Vector3 p, Vector3 a, Vector3 b )
{
    Vector3 pa = p - a;
    Vector3 ba = b - a;
    float h = Mathf.Clamp( Vector3.Dot(pa,ba)/Vector3.Dot(ba,ba), 0.0, 1.0 );
    return Vector3.Distance( pa - ba*h );
}

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try to sort the draw calls and see what happens!